# GNS3 sip/qt error

Tags: qt, pyqt, debian, python-sip

Have installed GNS3 on my Linux (Debian Strech) and getting below error message, please help, installed from package, OS updated. qt and sip at their newest version on my machine (installed).

**Fail update installation: No module named 'sip' **
**Can't import Qt modules: Qt and/or PyQt is probably not installed correctly...**

Any help/direction to solve the problem will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in-advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through these two pages - 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide the GNS3 version number.

Comment: Hi Peater, it's version 2.1 (the latest one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by installing from source file, by following this link, replaced 1.3.9 to 2.1.2 and worked.

https://gns3.com/discussions/getting-gns4-1-4beta1-gui-runnin

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still getting this error, I found that it was due to Xenial to Bionical upgrade that left a PPA hanging around, I guess there was a dependency missing. Here is exactly what I did to fix it.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gns3*
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y -u dist-upgrade
```

Then you can start gns3.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install this python module:

```
sudo pip install pyqt5
```

Answer (score 1):

i found out that the problem was a source in source.list.

in my case was the firefox quantum

Comment: Hi, Soy, Can you please share your solution, what did you do solve the problem.

Comment: what i did was a fresh debian installation, then just added the source in order to install firefox quantum and after that i delete that entry from the /etc/apt/sources.list.
Now i dont get that error anymore and i could install gns3 without any errors.
Check your /etc/apt/sources.list for any strange repo in my case was the firefox quantum repo

Answer (score 1):

I got this after upgrading Ubuntu to 20.04.  Only thing that worked was backing up my GNS3 folder with my project files, uninstalling gns3-server and gns3-gui, then re-installing.  Everything works now.